# Java: The declared package "substitution_ciphers" does not match the expected package "". VSCode

Tags: java, class, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I am doing a project for my school where i have to attach multiple package programs into a driver program. But sometimes VSCode allows me to create a package, and sometimes it kicks me with an error. Is there a solution to this?

I have attached a driver code and one of my package that was running before but now throws an error without any modifications.

I have a folder in my Windows desktop called 'Java Programs', which has all my previous java code. And in it, i have another sub-folder called 'substitution_ciphers', which has my packages.
The folder hierarchy is as follows- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Java programs\substitution_ciphers\CaesarCipher.java

Package program name "CaesarCipher.java"

```
package substitution_ciphers;

//import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaesarCipher {

    public static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public String encrypt(String plainText, int shiftKey) {

        plainText = plainText.toLowerCase();

        String cipherText = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {

            int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
            int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
            char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
            cipherText += replaceVal;

        }

        return cipherText;

    }

    public String decrypt(String cipherText, int shiftKey) {

        cipherText = cipherText.toLowerCase();

        String plainText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length(); i++) {

            int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(cipherText.charAt(i));
            int keyVal = (charPosition - shiftKey) % 26;

            if (keyVal < 0) {
                keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
            }
            char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
            plainText += replaceVal;

        }
        return plainText;
    }

}
```

Driver code name-"SubstitutionCiphersMain.java"

```
import substitution_ciphers.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SubstitutionCiphersMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CaesarCipher secret = new CaesarCipher();
        String message = new String();
        int key;
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the String for Encryption: ");
        message = input2.next();

        System.out.println("Enter the key value for Encryption : ");
        key = input2.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The Cipher Text is : " + secret.encrypt(message, key));
        System.out.println("The Plain Text is : " + secret.decrypt(secret.encrypt(message, key), key));



        //Viginere Cipher
        Vigenere Vig = new Vigenere();
        String Str = new String();
        String Keyword = new String();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Plain Text : ");
        Str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Key : ");
        Keyword = sc.nextLine();
        String str = Vig.LowerToUpper(Str);
        String keyword = Vig.LowerToUpper(Keyword);
     
        String key2 = Vig.generateKey(str, keyword);
        String cipher_text = Vig.cipherText(str, key2);
     
        System.out.println("Ciphertext : "+ cipher_text + "\n");
     
        System.out.println("Original/Decrypted Text : "+ Vig.originalText(cipher_text, key2));

    }
}
```

The second part of the driver code also contains driver code for another package program.

The only problem i am facing is this error msg-

```
> PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Java programs>  c:; cd
> 'c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Java programs'; &
> 'c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.35.0\scripts\launcher.bat'
> 'D:\Downloads\openlogic-openjdk-11.0.8+10-windows-x64\openlogic-openjdk-11.0.8+10-win-x64\bin\java.exe' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp'
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\15519510f0f6a195636945f80422590a\redhat.java\jdt_ws\Java
> programs_387fb779\bin' 'SubstitutionCiphersMain' Exception in thread
> "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>         The declared package "substitution_ciphers" does not match the expected package ""
> 
>         at CaesarCipher.<init>(CaesarCipher.java:1)
>         at SubstitutionCiphersMain.main(SubstitutionCiphersMain.java:7)
```

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Are there folders like `src` and `bin` in your project? Post the folder structure as screenshots cause your description is not clear enough.